# Mapbox basemap not showing 3D buildings when zoomed in

Tags: r, mapbox, deck.gl

When trying to use basemap style from mapbox in deckgl, the buildings are not showing up as 3D. Instead they are showing as 2D. How can I get the 3D view ?

First image shows output from R. Second one is the output I am expecting.

```
rm( list = ls() )

library( shiny ) ; library( shinydashboard ) ; library( dplyr ) ; library( deckgl ) ; library( mapdeck )

mapbox_api_token = 'your_mapbox_token'


ui <- basicPage( deckglOutput( 'map', height = '800px' ) )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$map = renderDeckgl({
    
    deckgl( zoom = 7, pitch = 35, latitude = 48.29507, longitude = 4.0731520 ) %>%

          add_mapbox_basemap( token = mapbox_api_token, style = mapdeck_style('dark') )
    
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Output in R]

[image: Expected output]